# Set syntax per project for files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: syntax, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to set syntax for specific file extensions for a project in Visual Studio Code?

For example set liquid syntax for all HTML files in project A and normal HTML otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can remap your files using the following setting:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.html": "liquid"
}
```

(assuming you're using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilding.language-liquid) which uses `liquid` as the language ID)

To apply this only to a particular project, just put this in the workspace-specific `settings.json` rather than the global one (`Preferences -> Settings -> Workspace Settings`). More info on settings can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).